# Is it possible to make the nvidia-smi command run on Windows from any location like on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, command, nvidia

I'm aware that you can't run `nvidia-smi` like you would on Linux on Windows, and you have to navigate to wherever the executable file is located in order to run it. Is there a way to run it in a Linux-like fashion from Windows?

I've looked at these questions:

1. [How do I run nvidia-smi on Windows? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100015/how-do-i-run-nvidia-smi-on-windows)
2. [How to set an alias in Windows Command Line? - Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line)

and have also tried adding the file path to my `Path` but it didn't work.

Does anybody know a way that I could make this work? Or is it not possible on Windows? Thanks.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Hi! I'm aware of what kind of questions are appropriate here, thanks for the reminder. I posted because the question that I originally referenced was posted here and because people who use NVIDIA GPU's usually program very closely to this command and so I thought it was appropriate. If the question gets closed then I'll move to Superuser.