# pytorch isn't running on gpu while true

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, conv-neural-network

I want to train on my local gpu but it's only running on cpu while torch.cuda.is_available() is actually true and i can see my gpu but it runs only on cpu , so how to fix it

my CNN model:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
# define the CNN architecture

class Net(nn.Module):
    ### TODO: choose an architecture, and complete the class
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        ## Define layers of a CNN
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, padding=1)
        # convolutional layer (sees 16x16x16 tensor)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, padding=1)
        # convolutional layer (sees 8x8x32 tensor)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, padding=1)
        
        # max pooling layer
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # linear layer (64 * 4 * 4 -> 500)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 28 * 28, 500)
        # linear layer (500 -> 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 133)
        # dropout layer (p=0.25)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.25)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        ## Define forward behavior
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        #print(x.shape)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        #print(x.shape)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        #print(x.shape)
        
        #print(x.shape)
        # flatten image input
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 28 * 28)
        # add dropout layer
        x = self.dropout(x)
        # add 1st hidden layer, with relu activation function
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        # add dropout layer
        x = self.dropout(x)
        # add 2nd hidden layer, with relu activation function
        x = self.fc2(x)
        
        return x

#-#-# You so NOT have to modify the code below this line. #-#-#

# instantiate the CNN
model_scratch = Net()

# move tensors to GPU if CUDA is available
if use_cuda:
    print("TRUE")
    model_scratch = model_scratch.cuda()
```

train function :

```
def train(n_epochs, loaders, model, optimizer, criterion, use_cuda, save_path):
    """returns trained model"""
    # initialize tracker for minimum validation loss
    valid_loss_min = np.Inf 

    loaders_scratch = {'train': train_loader,'valid': valid_loader,'test': test_loader}
    
    for epoch in range(1, n_epochs+1):
        # initialize variables to monitor training and validation loss
        train_loss = 0.0
        valid_loss = 0.0
        
        ###################
        # train the model #
        ###################
        model.train()
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(loaders['train']):
            # move to GPU
            if use_cuda:
                data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()
            ## find the loss and update the model parameters accordingly
            ## record the average training loss, using something like
            ## train_loss = train_loss + ((1 / (batch_idx + 1)) * (loss.data - train_loss))
            # clear the gradients of all optimized variables
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # forward pass: compute predicted outputs by passing inputs to the model
            output = model(data)
            # calculate the batch loss
            loss = criterion(output, target)
            # backward pass: compute gradient of the loss with respect to model parameters
            loss.backward()
            # perform a single optimization step (parameter update)
            optimizer.step()
            # update training loss
            train_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)
            
        ######################    
        # validate the model #
        ######################
        model.eval()
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(loaders['valid']):
            # move to GPU
            if use_cuda:
                data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()
            ## update the average validation loss
            output = model(data)
            # calculate the batch loss
            loss = criterion(output, target)
            # update average validation loss 
            valid_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)

        # calculate average losses
        train_loss = train_loss/len(train_loader.dataset)
        valid_loss = valid_loss/len(valid_loader.dataset)

        # print training/validation statistics 
        print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f} \tValidation Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
            epoch, 
            train_loss,
            valid_loss
            ))
        
        ## TODO: save the model if validation loss has decreased
        if valid_loss <= valid_loss_min:
            print('Validation loss decreased ({:.6f} --> {:.6f}).  Saving model ...'.format(
            valid_loss_min,
            valid_loss))
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path)
            valid_loss_min = valid_loss
        
    # return trained model
    return model

# train the model
loaders_scratch = {'train': train_loader,'valid': valid_loader,'test': test_loader}
model_scratch = train(100, loaders_scratch, model_scratch, optimizer_scratch, 
                      criterion_scratch, use_cuda, 'model_scratch.pt')

# load the model that got the best validation accuracy
model_scratch.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_scratch.pt'))
```

while i am getting `"TRUE"` in `torch.cuda.is_available()` but still not running on GPU
i am only running on CPU

the below picture shows that i am running on cpu with 62%

[image]

Comment: what does your `nvidia-smi` show? To find `nvidia-smi` you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57100016)

Comment: 7% CUDA utilization does not mean it is not using the GPU. It is a common misconception, your code is running on the GPU.

Comment: nvidi-smi shows 0% - 4% running

Comment: @ Dr. Snoopy , if i am running on gpu why cpu is increased 65% once i run the train function

Answer (score 2):

To utilize cuda in pytorch you have to specify that you want to run your code on gpu device.

a line of code like:

```
use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")
```

will determine whether you have cuda available and if so, you will have it as your device.

later in the code you have to pass your tensors and model to this device:

```
net = net.to(device)
```

and do the same for your other tensors that need to go to gpu, like test and training values.