# Running nvidia-smi from Windows PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to check my GPUs from Windows PowerShell with `nvidia-smi` but I can't get it to work.

I already [checked this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100015/how-do-i-run-nvidia-smi-on-windows) but I don't see a folder that starts with nvdm in my *C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository* directory.

I have two version of CUDA installed v8.0 and v11.2 but my System Variables (*CUDA_HOME, CUDA_PATH, CUDA_PATH_v11_2*) all point towards the v11.2 folder.

Is there a reason I would have CUDA but not `nvidia-smi` on my PC?

Comment: I'll run the search now but it will take a lot of time because I have a large hard drive. I don't recall installing a driver for Nvidia but I did install CUDA. Is there a way to use the Nvidia desktop manager to know where nvidia-smi.exe is installed?

Comment: Did you look in: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI` ?

Comment: I'll probably delete my question and just do that then. Before I do though can you tell me if there is a way to make it so that I can just type `nvidia-smi` in PowerShell and have that information pop up? The original post talks about making a shortcut but I'm wondering if PowerShell has something like `alias` in Linux where you can map commands.

Comment: If you add the path e.g. `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI` to your windows PATH variable, you can just open powershell and  you will be able to type `nvidia-smi` and it will work.  The method to modify a windows PATH variable (or any windows environment variable) is covered in many places on the web. From windows file explorer, right click on your PC icon, then select properties.  Then select advanced system settings, then click on the Environment variables button.  Add the path to your **system variables** `Path` variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure that `nvidia-smi.exe` is in the folder `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI`.  If it is not, you may wish to reinstall a NVIDIA GPU driver for your GPU, choosing a driver from [a CUDA toolkit installer](https://www.nvidia.com/getcuda).
2. add the path to your windows `Path` variable:

- open windows file explorer
- right click on your PC icon
- select properties
- select advanced system settings
- click the environment variables button
- Add the following path: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI` to the `Path` variable listed in the system variables section (select the variable, click "edit")
- save

3. Open a new power shell
4. type `nvidia-smi`

Comment: What do you do when you are on WSL and run `nvidia-smi` and it doesnt respond. It doesnt time out. It doesnt throw and error and ctrl-c doesnt kill the command

Comment: That has nothing to do with windows powershell or this question.

Comment: Has to do with `nvidia-smi`? Maybe it is another connection issue?

Comment: So this question is a suitable landing point for any question that has to do with `nvidia-smi`?  Sorry, I don't see it that way. You might wish to ask another question, or do some research.

Comment: Just wanted to see if you happened to know since your karma is super high. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case sommeone stumbles upon this problem in a more recent version:

Nvidia-smi commes included with cuda 12.4 (since cuda version 8 https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-deployment-kit).
And the exec file is located at `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_362f239e9bd019fc`.

This means that the command will work in CMD but not in PowerShell. To solve this you need to add the path to environment variables.