# PyTorch with GPU Support Ubuntu

Tags: pytorch, nvidia

I know this has been covered many times here, but I am still struggling to download PyTorch with NVIDIA GPU support on my end. I am using a Windows 10 OS but am trying to download Torch through an Ubuntu terminal because one of my project codes has a conflict with Windows.

I am running Python 3.9.12 and have a NVIDIA RTX 3090. I can provide other details about the hardware if needed.

I have followed this guide: [Jeff Heaton: PyTorch with GPU support](https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install/pytorch-install-jul-2020.ipynb) and tried to follow [PyTorch's own guidelines](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#windows-prerequisites) and failed. I have then tried them again after deleting previous NVIDIA drivers and CUDA versions via

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia\*
sudo apt-get remove --purge \*cuda\*
```

but failed again.

Many times, I encountered the [following error](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-make-sure-that-the-latest-nvidia-driver-is-installed-and-running/197141) when using

```
nvidia-smi
```

Thank you all for your time and please let me know what I could do.

Comment: how about installing a dual system that contains both Windows and Ubuntu on the same machine?

Comment: That was my next thought. I wanted to avoid the hassle of learning a new OS. I'll try that out soon and report my findings. Just curious though, what could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: I have no idea since I never tried an Ubuntu terminal on Windows before.  The problem may come from the difference in the default command, for example, calling nvidia-smi on windows need multiple steps (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100015/how-do-i-run-nvidia-smi-on-windows))

Comment: @CuCaRot Thanks for the tip. I ended up downloading Ubuntu on a separate SSD and now it works!